# Dual boot Windows and Ubuntu, can no longer access Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I had a working dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu for some time. I do not know when this occurred, but my computer stopped booting to GRUB and started going directly to Windows.

I can no longer see Ubuntu in the UEFI list in the BIOS. I have tried disabling and enabling secure boot, legacy mode, etc.

I cannot see Ubuntu in EasyUEFI. The partitions are clearly there but it is not in the boot order list.

rEFInd doesn't work.

What can I do?

Edit: i have run repair-boot, reinstalling grub. have used bcdedit to point at grub. I have fiddled around in bios. Nothing has made grub visible in the boot order.

Comment: Windows with updates will make itself first in UEFI boot list. And will turn on fast start up, so even if you turned it off before, you may need to do it again. You should not be turning UEFI/Legacy on/off. You should have all systems installed in one boot mode and only use that, they otherwise are not compatible. You may need to reinstall grub. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I put Windows at the bottom of the boot order and it still loaded Windows. Grub is no longer in the boot order.

Comment: I reinstalled grub, it didn't work.

Comment: What brand/model system? Post link to Summary report from Boot-Repair.